# Load a class dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to load a class (say Class1:Interface ) without knowing its name from an assembly.
My code looks like this:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyDll.dll");
Type t = (Type)a.GetTypes()[0];
(Interface) classInstance = (Interface) (ClasActivator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Based on the articles I found online and MSDN, `GetTypes()[0]` is suppose to return Class1 (there is only one class in MyDll.dll). However, my code returns `Class1.Properties.Settings`. So line 3 creates an exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Class1.Properties.Settings' to type Namespace.Interface'.
```

I really do not know why and how to fix this problem.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you could tag the original interface with an Attribute, and then check for all types with that attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly can hold more than one type (you likely have a `Settings.settings` file in the dll, it creates a class under the hood in the `Settings.Designer.cs` file), you only get the first class in your code which in your case turned out to be the `Settings` class, you need to go through all the types and search for the ones that have the interface you need.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyDll.dll");
Type[] allTypes = asm.GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in allTypes)
{
    // Only scan objects that are not abstract and implements the interface
    if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    {
        // Create a instance of that class...
        var inst = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        //do your work here, may be called more than once if more than one class implements IMyInterface
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check to find the first that implements the interface:

```
Type t = a.GetTypes()
  .FirstOrDefault(type => type.GetInterface(typeof(Interface).FullName) != null);
```

Comment: I might recommend the use of `Single`, since it seems there should be one, and only one, such class in the assembly.