# C# load newly created model to object dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently reinventing hot water. I want to create a basic orm tool that works like Entity Framework.

This is a console app, and it has a very simple flow:

1. It creates a scaffold string so I can create models from my database using EF Core.
2. The models are saved and added in the console application after I manually use the package manager console to execute the scaffold string
3. Here I am currently stuck: because the models are loaded and created using EF Core, I need to restart the application, and addres the model correctly so I can use the models as an object in the following code.

   ```
    Console.WriteLine($"New App Started : {args[0]}");

    objectName = args[0];

    // HERE I AM STUCK, because I would like to do this dynamically
    // var model = HowCanILoadTheModelDynamicaly(objectName);

    // Now I need to change this every time after I build the selected 
    // model using EF Core
    var model = new vwProductGroup();

    // 2 - 
    ProgramCreateClass.CreateNewDataServiceClass(
                ProgramCreateOrm.GenerateModelSet(model),
                ProgramCreateOrm.GenerateModelRead(model),
                ProgramCreateOrm.GenerateModelReadList(model),
                model.GetType() );

    Console.ReadLine();
   ```

The problem is that I don't know the content of the model, in this example `vwProductgroup`, before it is built using EF Core. So I can't create an interface.

I used several suggestions found online but I can't manage to get it to work properly.

Comment: var model = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"DataLibrary.DataModels.{args[0]}"));  did it

Comment: It's encouraged here to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

So after finding this [answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320787/load-a-class-dynamically-in-c-sharp), all I needed was this code:

```
var model = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"DataLibrary.DataModels.{args[0]}"));
```

This returned the needed type.